# Autolayout wrong margin

Tags: autolayout, margin

I have some problem setting margin on some view inside uiscrollview, I create via IB a scrollview and 3 view (they are outside of self.view), in my app I add this view with:

[scrollview addsubview:view1], eccc

after this I add constrains in this way:

```
[_ingredienti setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[_scrollView addSubview:_ingredienti];
[_scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_ingredienti
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                 toItem:_scrollView
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                             multiplier:1
                               constant:0]];

[_scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_ingredienti
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                 toItem:_scrollView
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                             multiplier:1
                               constant:0]];


[_scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_ingredienti
                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeftMargin
                                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                           toItem:_scrollView
                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                       multiplier:1
                                                         constant:self.scrollView.frame.size.width * 2]];
```

this for all 3 views, obviously NSLayoutAttributeLeftMargin has 3 different value, 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width and 2 * self.scrollView.frame.size.width, the problem is that the margin is wrong, is some pixel less then self.scrollView.frame.size.width, where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there are no constraints linking the `_ingredienti` top, bottom or right position to the `_scrollview`, which it needs to size its contentview. See the ["Pure Autolayout" subsection of Technical Note TN2154: UIScrollView And Autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html)